# How can I detect embeds in a message?

Tags: javascript, embed, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot read other bots' rich embeds, but I can't even find where to start doing it. I've read the docs, but  I still have no idea what to do...
Using `if(message.content.includes(x))` doesn't work, what can I do?

Comment: Debugging is your friend. `console.log` all the things, until you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a message is received, its embeds are stored in [`<Message>.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds): in order to read them, you can loop through that array and look at each embed's properties:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  for (let embed of message.embeds) { // these are some of the properties
    console.log(`
    Title: ${embed.title}
    Author: ${embed.author}
    Description: ${embed.description}
    `);
    for (let field of embed.field) {
      console.log(`
      Field title: ${field.name}
      Field value: ${field.value}
      `);
    }
  }
});
```

You can find these properties in the docs for [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) and [`MessageEmbedField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbedField).

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation worked greatly, my bot is running and finding malicious embeds!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)