# How can a bot read embed messages sent by another bot and post a message if it contains a specific content?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to code a Discord bot that would read embed messages sent by another bot and ping a specific role if the embed contains '(FREE)' in the title, as displayed here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPsR1.png

Unfortunately, my code produces nothing. I don't run into any error, the bot simply doesn't post a message when conditions are matched to do so — yet it is online and has the permissions to post messages in the channel.

Any help would be really appreciated. I went through all the questions related to this topic on SO, but I couldn't find a working solution to my issue. I'd like to mention that I'm a beginner in JS.

Thank you so much.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_WEBHOOKS"] })

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in...`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.embeds) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title === '(FREE)') {
        return message.channel.send('@Free mint')
      }
    }
})
```

Edit: I believe my question is different from the one suggested in the comment as I'm looking for specific content in the embed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect embeds in a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771822/how-can-i-detect-embeds-in-a-message)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the bot work with the following code, thanks @Gavin for suggesting it:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_WEBHOOKS"] })

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in...`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  for (let embed of message.embeds) {
    if (embed.title.includes('FREE')) {
      return message.channel.send("<@&" + roleId + ">")
    }
  }
});
```